# Called method is not getting authorized in spring security

Tags: java, spring

I'm using spring security and I've 2 methods in my MovieService-

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_DIRECTOR')")
public Map<String, Movie> getAllMovies() {
.......
.......
}
```

And another method is -

```
public Movie getMovieByMovieCode(String movieCode) {
        Map<String, Movie> movies = getAllMovies();
        Movie movie = movies.get(movieCode);
        return movie;
}
```

As shown in code, I'm calling `getAllMovies()` method from inside the `getMovieByMovieCode()` method. So, if a user who does **NOT** have `ROLE_DIRECTOR` role, it tries to access `getMovieByMovieCode()` method and from inside this method, `getAllMovies()` method is also accessed.

But the expected behavior is that this user should not be able to access `getAllMovies()` method as this user does not have role ROLE_DIRECTOR.

How can I achieve this behavior? Do I need to use `<dispatcher>` inside filter mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security authorization using annotations is implemented using Spring AOP proxies. That, among other things, means that whenever you are calling methods on the current object, you are referencing the object itself, not the proxy. That is why authentication is not done. The simple workaround would be to annotate the getMovieByMovieCode with the @PreAuthorize annotation too.

Here is some helpfull reading on AOP proxies: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies

Comment: This link was helpful and i got the point that the call that i'm making to getAllMovies() method is not on proxy object, It's a direct call so any advice won't come in to play. And Now i've one more doubt-

Suppose now i annotated getMovieByMovieCode(String movieCode) with @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_AUDIENCE')") annotation and getAllMovies() method is unchanged. And the calling user has only ROLE_AUDIENCE role. Then also authorization doesn't take place. Is it still a direct call?

Comment: I got the answer. When we annotate getMovieByMovieCode(String movieCode) with @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_AUDIENCE')"), user is authorized to access this method as this user has only ROLE_AUDIENCE. and the call to getAllMovies() is still a direct call(NOT on proxy reference). And hence in this case also advices related to getAllMovies() won't come into play.

I also tried to make a call on proxy object as opposed to direct call as shown in this link  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies

Comment: For making a proxy call, I added '<aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true" />' in my spring-servlet.xml file. And made a proxy call as follows-

`MovieService movieService =(MovieService)AopContext.currentProxy();
Map<String, Movie> movies = movieService.getAllMovies();`

And now it's a proxy call so if user doesn't have _ROLE_DIRECTOR_ role then that user won't be able to access `getAllMovies()` method.